# Content of matrix in TikZ doesn't appear properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I've  written the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
    {
        e\subset\Gamma & f(e)\subset \Gamma' \\
        \mathbb{R}\supset [0,l_{\Gamma}(e)] & [0,S_{f,e}l_{\Gamma}(e)] \subset\mathbb{R} \\};
    \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [left] {} (m-2-1)
    edge node [above] {$f|_e$} (m-1-2)
    (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge node [below] {$t\mapsto S_{f,e}t$}
    (m-2-2)
    (m-2-2) edge node [right] {} (m-1-2)
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

and what I get is

[image]

In the right and down corner why isn't there `[0,S_{f,e}l_{\Gamma}(e)] \subset\mathbb{R}` and I get only the `\subset\mathbb{R}`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code.

Comment: I'd also suggest using [`tikz-cd`](https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) for diagrams like that. It makes them much easier to write and understand I feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using square brackets `[]` inside the `tikzpicture` and they are getting consumed. If you want them to be displayed, you can use the proper `\left[` and `\right]` notation, as in:

`\left[0,S_{f,e}l_{\Gamma}(e)\right]` and they will appear:

[image]

Comment: You're right! Thanks!